# Animate a List from LeftView from Left to Right in Android?

Tags: android, animation

This Animation brings a Listview from top to bottom .... Now i want to animate it to left to Right .... What will be the     TranslateAnimation()  Co-ordinates.The Sliding Menu Like google .

```
private void SetMenuVisible() {
    if (visiable) {
        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -1000);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        MenuBar.startAnimation(animation);
        MenuBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cornerIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.actionbar_icon_down);
        visiable = false;
    } else {
        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -1000, 0);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        MenuBar.startAnimation(animation);
        MenuBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cornerIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.actionbar_icon_up);
        visiable = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29):

```
TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

You need to work with `fromXDelta` & `toXDelta` to get animation from left to right

Eg: Left to Right

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500, 0, 0);
```

Right to Left

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(500, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I was trying to Like Gmail Menu... On First Scenario it will come from  left to Visible and then it will go back Right to Invisible ..Cann you help me with that

Comment: Its same as you have posted, just replace with left to right and right to left

Comment: Try changing the values for duration.

Comment: And if you want to make menu like Gmail, please check `NavigationDrawer` in the docs